# 2 Dropdown Checklist

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently working on a two-dropdown multiselect menu, and I'm facing a challenge with the dropdown behavior. Specifically, I want the first dropdown and its options to stay fixed at the top, ensuring that clicking on it doesn't cause the second dropdown to shift downward.

[Here is the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlC18.png):

[image]

[Every time I click on the first dropdown menu, the second dropdown menu gets dragged to the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh8kY.png):

[image]

```js
const selectBtn = document.querySelector(".select-btn");
const item = document.querySelectorAll(".items");

selectBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  selectBtn.classList.toggle("open");
});

item.forEach(items => {
  items.addEventListener("click", () => {
    items.classList.toggle("checked");

    let checked = document.querySelectorAll(".checked"),
      btnText = document.querySelector(".btn-text");

    if (checked && checked.length > 0 && checked.length <= 1) {
      btnText.innerText = `${checked.length} Selected Item`;
    } else if (checked && checked.length > 1) {
      btnText.innerText = `${checked.length} Selected Items`;
    } else {
      btnText.innerText = "Select Year and Semester";
    }
  });
})
```

```css
:root {
  --yellow: #FFD83A;
  --gray: #D0D0D0;
  --lightGray: #e1e1e1;
  --blue: #004AAD;
  --black: #141413;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 22rem;
  height: 35rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/*Navbar*/

.navbar h2 {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

.navbar ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  margin: 15px 4px 5px;
}

.navbar li img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}


/*Header*/

.header p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: .8rem;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}


/*drop-down Checkbox*/

.container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 290px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  margin: 0px 30px;
}

.select-btn {
  background-color: var(--gray);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.select-btn .btn-text {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.select-btn .arrow-down {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.select-btn.open .arrow-down {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.arrow-down .arrow-icon {
  font-size: 1rem;
}


/*drop-down Items*/

.list-items {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  background-color: var(--gray);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  font-size: 1rem;
  display: none;
}

.select-btn.open~.list-items {
  display: block;
}

.list-items .items {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.list-items .items:hover {
  background-color: var(--yellow);
}

.items .checkbox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1.5px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  transition: all 0.3 ease-in-out;
}

.items.checked .checkbox {
  color: var(--yellow)
}

.checkbox .check-icon {
  font-size: 0.6rem;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: all 0.3 ease-in-out;
}

.items.checked .check-icon {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<section class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="select-btn">
      <span class="btn-text">Select Year and Semester</span>

      <span class="arrow-down">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-chevron-down arrow-icon"></i>
                </span>
    </div>

    <ul class="list-items">
      <li class="items">
        <span class="checkbox">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-circle check-icon"></i>
                    </span>
        <span class="item-text">1st Year 1st Semester</span>
      </li>

      <li class="items">
        <span class="checkbox">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-circle check-icon"></i>
                    </span>
        <span class="item-text">1st Year 2nd Semester</span>
      </li>

      <li class="items">
        <span class="checkbox">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-circle check-icon"></i>
                    </span>
        <span class="item-text">2nd Year 1st Semester</span>
      </li>

      <li class="items">
        <span class="checkbox">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-circle check-icon"></i>
                    </span>
        <span class="item-text">2nd Year 2nd Semester</span>
      </li>

      <li class="items">
        <span class="checkbox">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-circle check-icon"></i>
                    </span>
        <span class="item-text">3rd Year 1st Semester</span>
      </li>

      <li class="items">
        <span class="checkbox">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-circle check-icon"></i>
                    </span>
        <span class="item-text">3rd Year 2nd Semester</span>
      </li>

      <li class="items">
        <span class="checkbox">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-circle check-icon"></i>
                    </span>
        <span class="item-text">4th Year 1st Semester</span>
      </li>

      <li class="items">
        <span class="checkbox">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-circle check-icon"></i>
                    </span>
        <span class="item-text">4th Year 2nd Semester</span>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="select-btn">
      <span class="btn-text">Select Subject</span>

      <span class="arrow-down">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-chevron-down arrow-icon"></i>
                </span>
    </div>


  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: you can set the position absolut of dropdown ```.list-items {position: absolute;z-index: 111;width: 100%; ... ....```

Answer (score -1):

make the

```js
.list-items {
  position: absolute;
}
```

It should work

Comment: thank you so much sir, I also added z-index:1; to make sure that the option will always stays at top

Comment: if it worked, kindly upvote.

Comment: This is what it says sir "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Comment: ok just acccept the answer then